# Inherit from two (or more) build in Objects in JS (Map, EventTarget)

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I'm not Noob in JS and I know that technically there is no *right* way to inherit from multiple classes. so my question is very straightforward

Is there any idea how can I create a class or just an object that acts as it inherits from two builds in JS Native object. especially `EventTarget` and another object.

I try :

```
var map = new Map();
var eventtarget = new EventTarget();
mix = Object.create({...Map.prototype, ...EventTarget.prototype});
Object.assign(mix, et , map);
```

It seems not working because the methods in`Map.prototype` are not itrables 
also using `Object.assign({}, Map.prototype, ...EventTarget.prototype)` as the same effect.

Another try:

```
class Base5 extends Map{
 constructor(){
    super();
    var eventTarget = new EventTarget();
    Object.assign(this,eventTarget);
 }
}

Base5.prototype = Object.create(Base5.prototype)
Object.assign(Base5.prototype,EventTarget.prototype); 

//    that seem to work
const b5 = new Base5();
b5.set('foo','bar');
//    but... 
b4.addEventListener('fire', _=>_ )
// throw Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation at <anonymous>:1:4
```

This one worked but it not generic

```
const wm = new WeakMap();

class Base6 extends Map{
 constructor(){
    super();
    wm.set(this, new EventTarget() )
 }
 addEventListener(){ 
    wm.get(this).addEventListener(...arguments)
 }
 dispatchEvent(){
    wm.get(this).dispatchEvent(...arguments)
 }
 removeEventListener(){
   wm.get(this).removeEventListener(...arguments)
 }
}

const b6 = new Base6();
b6.set('foo','bar'); // Map(1) {"foo" => "bar"}
b6.addEventListener('foo', e=>console.log(e) );
b6.dispatchEvent( new Event('foo') )
```

So anyone can come with a better approach?

Maybe [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) can help here somehow

Comment: What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: How create object that can be instance of two build in JS Objects. like `Map` and `EventTarget`  Or ... `Set` . basically instance of two third party classes that the programmer not have a way to edit .  But I am particularly interested in the solution of combine `Map` + `EventTarget`

Comment: That doesn't explain the higher level problem. It is more like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Short answer, it can't be done: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#No_multiple_inheritance

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl for the definition. my real problem is to create `Map` like object that can emit every time someone `set` or `get` it property . but that out of scope of this question.

Comment: You can't. JavaScript doesn't support multiple inheritance. You will probably need to write a `class extends Map` and then manually mixin all the `EventEmitter` poperties and methods.

Comment: @mbojko sure it can be done. For basic custom Object I already bring a solutions. the documentation  talk about that there is no right syntax to do that . but there is a lot of answers here that can teach how to `mixes` and pesado inherited from multiple constructors

Comment: @Bergi I all ready tried that  and write my conclusions. for some reason it not work ( properly I miss something )

Comment: @charlietfl sure. I'm using `Proxy` for that . My question is generic question about create object that `inherited like` from build in JS object...

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed you are talking about native `EventTarget` (DOM) not `EventEmitter` (node.js). Then no, it's not possible to use a mixin strategy, the `WeakMap` (or just normal property) with `Base5` as a *wrapper* object is the only viable approach.

Comment: *"...It seems not working because Map.prototype are not itrable..."* I thought Map was iterable `Map.prototype.forEach()`, `Map.prototype.keys()`, `Map.prototype.values()`, `Map.prototype.entries()`,  `Map.prototype[@@iterator]()`

Comment: @zer00ne sure it confusing `Map` are iterable  but methods of `Map.prototype` are not. I will fix My wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55432354/3791358) inspired me to research a little bit more and come up with this solution, which improves some aspects of his solution:

1. Weak bind for inherited function.
2. Ability to use the Mixed Class as a prototype to extend **another** custom class.

If you like my answer, don't forget to thumb up his answer too.

Anyway, here is a [factory function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1) that extends multiple native classes. This is a start and it probably isn't perfect, so feel free to participate in the improvement of this snippet:

```js
function CreateMixedClasess (...classes) {
  return function Mixed () {
    const instances = [this, ...classes.map(cls => new cls(...arguments))]

    const weakbind = (proxy, fn, obj) => new Proxy(fn, {
      apply (fn, thisArg, props) {
        return fn.apply(proxy === thisArg ? obj : thisArg, props)
      }
    })

    return new Proxy(this, {
      get (_, prop, proxy) {
        obj = instances.find(obj => prop in obj)
        const val = Object(obj)[prop]
        return typeof val === 'function' ? weakbind(proxy, val, obj) : val
      },
      has (_, prop) { // Optional: if you care about the `in` operator
        return instances.some(obj => prop in obj)
      }
    })
  }
}


// class Mixed extends CreateMixedClasess (Map, EventTarget) {}
const Mixed = CreateMixedClasess(Map, EventTarget)
const obj12 = new Mixed()
obj12.set('foo', 'bar')
console.log('Map contains: ', Object.fromEntries(obj12))
obj12.addEventListener('foo', e => console.log('Event object type: ', e.type))
obj12.dispatchEvent(new Event('foo'))
obj12.a = 3
obj12.myfn = function () { console.log(this.a) }
obj12.myfn() // 3
obj12.myfn.call({a: 4}) // 4

class MyAwsomeClass extends CreateMixedClasess (Map, EventTarget) {
  constructor () {
    super(...arguments)
    this.a = 33
  }
  logA () {
    console.log(this.a)
  }
}

const myAwsomeInstance = new MyAwsomeClass(obj12)
myAwsomeInstance.has('foo') // true
```

Comment: Definitely a good idea to detect whether the member function is called with the proxy as `this` and only then intervene.

Answer (score 1):

For now, and for other that seek solution to that problem I come with this soulution

```
const wm = new WeakMap();

function Emitter(Base) {
   return class extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        wm.set(this, new EventTarget())
    }

    addEventListener() {
        wm.get(this).addEventListener(...arguments)
    }

    dispatchEvent() {
        wm.get(this).dispatchEvent(...arguments)
    }

    removeEventListener() {
        wm.get(this).removeEventListener(...arguments)
    }
  }
}

// how to use
const EmitterableMap = Emitter(Map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function, that creates private instances of the base classes, and returns a proxy that dispatches property retrievals to one of those objects. The base classes could be passed to the constructor to keep it generic:

```
createMix(Map, EventTarget)
```

Several things will remain problematic. One blocking issue is that method calls often need `this` to be set to the base object for them to work. A work around may be to return a bound method, knowing that this in itself can have undesirable effects (e.g. the customer could not take the method and bind it themselves to something else -- if that made sense at all).

For sure this does not solve all potential issues, but it seems to work in very basic usage:

```js
function createMix(...classes) {
    const obj = {};
    const instances = [obj, ...classes.map(cls => new cls)];
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(obj, prop) {
            obj = instances.find(obj => prop in obj);
            const val = Object(obj)[prop];
            return typeof val === "function" ? val.bind(obj) : val;
        },
        has(obj, prop) { // Optional: if you care about the `in` operator
            return instances.some(obj => prop in obj);
        }
    });
}

// Tiny test
const obj = createMix(Map, EventTarget);
obj.set('foo','bar'); 
console.log("Map contains: ", Object.fromEntries(obj));
obj.addEventListener('foo', e => console.log("Event object type: ", e.type) );
obj.dispatchEvent( new Event('foo') );
```

As this function returns a container object, it will not be `instanceof` any of the base classes passed to the function.

Comment: pretty slick and advanced answer. I like the  `Object(obj)[prop]` to avoid from the `undefind` case. and `Object.fromEntries(map)`. you probably  can make it simpler if you concat the `this` with the other `instances` . and call it `CreateMix`. Totally worth reading so I mark it as right answer until better one become

Comment: Yes, you got the reason for that `Object` call right. I incorporated your idea of putting the container object in the list of other objects. I would not name the function `CreateMix`, as it is not called as a constructor (with `new`), but that is personal taste, and could be changed to be one.

Comment: Ok, Because you are used the `this` inside `createMix()` and without `new` it equal to `window` I assume you plan to use it with `new`

Comment: Yes, in my answer's first version I wrote it as a constructor, but then changed my mind and made it into a factory function, but forgot to replace one `this`.

Comment: Ok sure. 
It will be nice if I can bring some parameters to the constructs functions. for example init the `Map` with `[['a',1],['b',2]]` or  another `map`

Comment: Then it might be easier to not pass classes to the functions, but instances, like `createMix(new Map([['a',1]]), new EventTarget())`. The `instances` variable would then become the function parameter: `function createMix(...instances)`. Just the newly created object would need to be added to it.

Comment: I've researched more your solution and   I came up with another version that can be extended more. I invite you to check it out.